# Debug icons do not appear

Tags: visual-studio

My visual studio does not show the icons in debug mode why?

Actual:
[Actual Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejTwT.png)

Expected: [Expected Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPl6Z.png)

Everything worked perfectly, but from time to time, the icons stopped.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.3.0
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.0+26730.3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual Basic 2017   
Microsoft Visual Basic 2017

Visual C# 2017   
Microsoft Visual C# 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

For bugs like this it's best to provide feedback from VS directly. You can report bugs by using the "Send Feedback" tool in Visual Studio.

Which can be found either in the top title bar:

[image]

Or in the Help menu `Help->Send Feedback->Report a Problem...`:

[image]